# Comparing a float and an int

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

Due to safety reasons, I need to perform the same computation twice, one time with only integer (int32) variables and another time with only float (float32) variables. At the end of the computation a comparison between the two results is taking place.

I read the article about [comparing floating point numbers](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).

There are few things I don't understand:

1. I haven't the following compression for float number: Assuming *a* and *b* are floats, is this way of comparison correct:

   ```
   if !(a > b) && !(a < b) is true, then _a_ and _b_ are probably identical otherwise not.
   ```
2. If I cast a float number to integer, I get the integer part of the number, why by using an union object and there defining the same memory as *int32* and *float32* I get different solution? Doesn't it cast the float number to *int32* as well?

Comment: What does "I haven't the following compression for float number" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**why by using an union object and there defining the same memory as int32 and float32 i get different solution?**

The only reason the `float/int union` even makes sense is by virtue of the fact that both `float` and `int` share a `storage size` of `32-bits`. What you are missing is an understanding that `floats` (in fact all floating point numbers) are stored in `IEEE-754 Floating Point Format` (floats are **single-precision**, doubles are **double-precision**, etc..)

When you use the `float/int union` trick, you see the `integer value` that is the `integer equivalent` to the `IEEE-754 Single-Precision Floating Point Format` for the `float`. The two values have **nothing** to do with representing the same numeric **value**. You can just look at the memory they occupy as either a `float` or as an `integer` by virtue of them both occupying `32-bits` of memory. If you look through the `float` window, you see what those `32-bits` mean as a `float`. If on the other hand, you look at the same `32-bits` as an `integer`, you see nothing more that what those same `32-bits` would be if taken as an `integer`. An example looking at the binary representation usually helps.

Take for example, the `float` value `123.456`. If you look at the `32-bits` in memory you see:

```
The float value entered : 123.456001

binary value in memory  : 01000010-11110110-11101001-01111001

As unsigned integer     : 1123477881
```

The IEEE-754 Single Precision Floating Point Representation is a specific floating point format in memory comprised of the following 3-components:

```
 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
|s|      exp      |                  mantissa                   |
```

Where `s` is the `sign-bit`, `exp` is the `biased exponent` with the remaining `23-bits` called the `mantissa`.There is no way you can expect to cast the `float 123.456` and get anything close to `integer 123`, you are off by about `7 orders of magnitude`

**Doesn't it cast the float number to int32 as well?**

Answer: **No**

Answer (score 2):

1. False. For instance, `a` and `b` are both `nan`, in which case `a < b`, `a > b`, `a == b` are all false.
2. Because integers and floating point numbers are represented differently. When you cast a `float` to `int` (e.g, `1.0f` to `1`), their memory are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

1. False

   Comparison in floating-point types works the same as in integer types for normal types. `a == b` always return true if the value of a is exactly equal to b, i.e `12.345 == 12.345` but `12.345 < 12.346`. If you need to compare that the value are close enough to each other, use an epsilon like instead of `==`. However for special numbers like [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) or [Inf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Infinities) then things are different. Comparisons with NaN returns false for all operators except `!=`
2. Because one works with values and the other works with object representation

   A simple cast to int like `(int)some_double_value` will return the **value** of some_double_value. However if you store it into a union and read out the integer like that, it'll return the **representation** in memory of the float

   For example `(int)2.5 == 2` but the binary representation of 2.5 in [IEEE-754 double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) is 0x4004000000000000