# What does if( c == (int) c) mean?

Tags: c++, if-statement

This is a code for pythagorean triplet. Can somebodby explain the working of `if` statement below.

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    float c;

    //calculate the another side using Pythagoras Theorem
    //a*a + b*b = c*c
    //c = sqrt(a*a+b*b)
    //maximum length should be equal to 30
    for(a=1;a<=30;a++)
    {
        for(b=1;b<=30;b++)
        {
            c = sqrt(a*a+b*b);
            if(c == (int)c)
            {
                printf("(%d, %d, %d)\n",a,b,(int)c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The if statement is just checking whether the floating point variable `c` is same as its integer equivalent (by type casting `c` to `int`).

Comment: This is an attempt to check if the result of `sqrt` is integer, however, it will fail if the result is outside of the `int` type range.

Comment: Generally speaking, whenever someone feels the need to do a C-style cast (like `(int) c`) then it should be taken as a red flag that there's something wrong going on.

Comment: So we are to check if calculated `c` is an int/whole number ? if it is, then we take it as a side of the triangle.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can u explain?

Answer (score 0):

It is checking whether the value is integral. 'c' is a float, the cast drops any fractional part. The original value of 'c' is then checked against the result of that cast. If they match then the original c was an integral value (note that even with this cast there are plenty of integral values that will fail this test, any value of 'c' larger than std::numeric_limits::max())

Comment: It's worse than that.  The integer 16,777,217 can't be accurately represented as a float according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e

Answer (score 0):

This if statement does not have to work because floating point (`float`, `double`, etc) representations in the processor are different from integers (`int`, `char`, etc). Therefore, in the general case, this kind of operator is erroneous.

Floating-point numbers are sometimes impossible to represent exactly as an integer (especially as a result of some kind of calculation) (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076038/comparing-a-float-and-an-int)), and integers are always represented exactly.

In your case, one way to make the if statement correct is to write it like this:

```cpp
if (fabs(c - roundf(c)) < eps) {
    ...
}
```

where `eps` is required accuracy. For example,

```cpp
float eps = 1e-12;  // 10^(-12)
```